# Problem with DATE type in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

I'm trying to CREATE a TABLE with an attribute of type DATE in Microsoft SQL Server 2008. However, when I execute the query,

I get the error:

```
Column, parameter, or variable #3: Cannot find data type DATE.
```

I consulted the documentation, and it indicated that DATE is a valid type in SQL Server. It works if I replace "DATE" with "DATETIME". My guess is I'm missing something really simple, but I just started learning SQL and SQL Server; does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you really want to use DATE, you could change the compatibility level of the database.

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
```

That would switch the database to 2008 compatibility, and you should be able to use the DATE datatype.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

Answer (score 7):

It is possible that your database is 8.0 or 9.0 compatible. In this case you cannot use DATE type.

Comment: If so, are there any alternatives?

Comment: Yes, you can use DATETIME type.

Comment: Or preferably: switch the database compatibility level to "100" (SQL Server 2008) to actually use the SQL Server 2008 features!

Comment: Sure. I think database owners may have some reasons to keep this database in old compatibility mode, but if not - this is the solution, too.